# Hola amigos, mi maestro me pidio crear un programa que modele figuras geometricas con el metodo class pero no e podido lograr hacerlo, colaboren plis

Tags: python

Se requiere un programa que modele varias figuras geométricas: el círculo, el rectángulo, el
cuadrado y el triángulo rectángulo.

• El círculo tiene como atributo su radio en centímetros.
• El rectángulo, su base y altura en centímetros.
• El cuadrado, la longitud de sus lados en centímetros.
• El triángulo, su base y altura en centímetros
• Se requieren métodos para determinar el área y el perímetro de cada figura geométrica.

Además, para el triángulo rectángulo se requiere:
• Un método que calcule la hipotenusa del rectángulo.

• Un método para determinar qué tipo de triángulo es:

o Equilátero: todos sus lados son iguales.
o Isósceles: tiene dos lados iguales.
o Escaleno: todos sus lados son diferentes.

Se debe desarrollar una implementación de prueba para crear las cuatro figuras y probar los
métodos respectivos.

Comment: Las solicitudes para realizar tus deberes no son bien recibidos por la comunidad del sitio, intenta desarrollarlo, cuando tengas problemas puedes editar la pregunta para un problema especifico.

Comment: Mucha suerte con tu tarea.

Comment: Es imposible determinar si un triángulo rectángulo es isósceles, equilátero o escaleno a partir de su base y su altura sin especificar de qué altura se trata...

Answer (score -4, accepted):

¡Claro! Aquí tienes un ejemplo de cómo puedes implementar las figuras geométricas en Python utilizando clases:

```
  import math

class Figura:
    def calcularArea(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("Método no implementado")

    def calcularPerimetro(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("Método no implementado")

class Circulo(Figura):
    def __init__(self, radio):
        self.radio = radio

    def calcularArea(self):
        return math.pi * self.radio**2

    def calcularPerimetro(self):
        return 2 * math.pi * self.radio

class Rectangulo(Figura):
    def __init__(self, base, altura):
        self.base = base
        self.altura = altura

    def calcularArea(self):
        return self.base * self.altura

    def calcularPerimetro(self):
        return 2 * (self.base + self.altura)

class Cuadrado(Figura):
    def __init__(self, lado):
        self.lado = lado

    def calcularArea(self):
        return self.lado**2

    def calcularPerimetro(self):
        return 4 * self.lado

class TrianguloRectangulo(Figura):
    def __init__(self, base, altura):
        self.base = base
        self.altura = altura

    def calcularArea(self):
        return 0.5 * self.base * self.altura

    def calcularPerimetro(self):
        return self.base + self.altura + self.calcularHipotenusa()

    def calcularHipotenusa(self):
        return math.sqrt(self.base**2 + self.altura**2)

    def determinarTipoTriangulo(self):
        if self.base == self.altura:
            return "Equilátero"
        elif self.base == self.altura/2 or self.altura == self.base/2:
            return "Isósceles"
        else:
            return "Escaleno"

# Implementación de prueba
circulo = Circulo(5)
rectangulo = Rectangulo(4, 6)
cuadrado = Cuadrado(3)
triangulo = TrianguloRectangulo(5, 8)

print("Área del círculo:", circulo.calcularArea())
print("Perímetro del círculo:", circulo.calcularPerimetro())
```

Recuerda que este es solo un ejemplo y puedes adaptarlo o expandirlo según tus necesidades. Espero que te sea útil y te ayude a completar tu tarea. ¡Buena suerte!

Comment: La pregunta tiene el tag Python. El código que tú publicas está escrito en Java.

Comment: ademas, tu respuesta es solo codigo, sin ningun tipo de explicacion....

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución. Mira [cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sólo matizar que lo que llamas en tu código base y altura de un triángulo rectángulo, en realidad son los dos catetos. También son base y altura de un triángulo su hipotenusa y la distancia entre ésta y el vértice de su ángulo rectángulo.

Comment: Debería haber una clase base con los métodos "calcularArea", "calcularPerimetro", y todas las demás clases (Circulo, Rectangulo, etc) derivar de ella. POO 101.

Comment: @CandidMoe Agradezco tu opinión. En este caso, he optado por implementar las clases de forma individual en lugar de utilizar una clase base común. Creo que ambas aproximaciones tienen sus ventajas y dependen del contexto del proyecto. ¡Cada enfoque tiene sus méritos!

Comment: Si vas a implementar la clase abstracta `Figura`, debería servir para asegurar que las clases derivadas implementan los métodos correctos. Usualmente esos métodos abstractos lanzan la excepción [`NotImplementedError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#NotImplementedError).

Comment: @JorgeLuis listo

Comment: Recuerda revisar: [No utilizar ChatGPT](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5462/pol%c3%adtica-temporal-chatgpt-est%c3%a1-prohibido)

Comment: @JorgeLuis Y si lo saco con con otra IA? No estaría incumpliendo

Comment: @EnriqueVázquez Esa pregunta deberías hacerla en [Meta Stack Overflow](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com)